# Transfer iOS app from one Apple account to other

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I want to transfer my iOS app from one apple store account to other. For both accounts I have team agent role and I have logged in with same access details.

At documentation, I found this article and I want to follow similar steps from my side - [Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

But at above reference link, I found this option/link - **Transfer App**:
[image]

When I actually logged into my account, I can't able to find this kind of option to move app from one account to another. Here is screenshot for my account:

[image]

So actually where is the app transfer option?

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your bundle ID is backwards. `com.gamingguruz.exnext` would be the correct format.

Answer (score 11):

If you haven't published a version of the app yet, don't worry about transferring it, because you can't.

1. Log into the team you want to transfer *to*.
2. Click on `My Apps`.
3. Click the `+` to create a new app, as you did in the other account.
4. Fill it in.
5. Forget about the old record - it's just metadata. If it bothers you, you can change almost everything about the unpublished record and use it for something else.

### When To Transfer Apps

There's no point in transferring an empty app record. Simply create a new entry in the other iTunes Connect account. The whole point of an app transfer is to preserve reviews and the upgrade path for users. If those weren't a concern, you'd just create a new app entry anyway.

The only downside to this is that you lose the original app identifier (`com.example.appname`) but since nobody sees that, it doesn't really matter. Adjust your code signing certificates and you'll be fine.

### When Transferring Apps Is Allowed

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html), there are a few conditions for transferring apps:

- Both developer accounts must be completely set up.
- The app must have a published version.
- The app cannot use entitlements for iCloud or Passbook.
- The app cannot use (or have ever used) In-App Purchase subscriptions
- The app cannot be cannot be In Review.
- Any in-app purchases for the app must also not be in review.
- Any in-app purchases for the app must not have product IDs that are the same as in-app purchase products on the destination account.

### What Transfers, What Doesn't

These things transfer over:

- **Bundle ID:** The app's bundle identifier
- **iTunes Connect App Record:** Metadata (the description and the rest of the app store entry.) The new team name will appear under the app name once the transfer is complete.
- **User Upgrades:** Users will see the next update from the new account.

These things don't transfer over:

- **Download Stats:** App download number don't transfer over. The new developer account will start from zero downloads.
- **Keychain Access:** Keychain access is lost for transferred apps, because the team prefix changes.
- **Handoff, Universal Links, Shared Web Credentials**: If you're using an `apple-app-site-association` file, you'll need to modify it to include the old app identifier as well as the new one. You want both, because you don't want to break functionality for users who didn't upgrade yet.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned anywhere, 'what doesn't' transfer, according to my research. Really appreciate it.

Comment: So does that mean push notifications will stop working? and process would be Create new dist. certificates, APNS certificates and provisioning profile and resubmit the app?

Comment: @Nil 
"Push notifications apps
Associated client SSL certificates for push notifications aren’t transferred. If the app uses Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), the recipient needs to create a client SSL certificate using the recipient’s developer account to reenable it."

Comment: Link to the full documentation here:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f

Comment: Yes, but this does not requires resubmission of the app right? as Push is only associated with App ID

Comment: @Moshe Thanks for great explanation. Does "Download Stats" mean number of downloads that is used for ranking in AppStore?

Answer (score 4):

Discussion with Apple Developer support for **App transfer related queries**, which may help some one

**1. Is App transfer between one developer account to another possible ?**
**Ans:** Yes

**2. Can you transfer an App that is live on App Store which is published from a Apple Developer Account can be transferred to an Apple Enterprise Account ?**
**Ans:** No

**3. After creating new developer account can I transfer the App quickly ?**
**Ans:** After initiating a transfer from sending account the receiving account need to accept the App transfer request, and after accepting the request it will take 1 or 2 days for the transfer to complete. During this transfer process the will not be available in appStore.

**4. How many days will it take to create a new Developer account?

Ans:** It is not same all the time, but usually takes 2 to 3 days.

**5. Post expiry of the developer account can I transfer the App to a new developer account?

Ans:** No post expiry of your developer account you can’t initiate the transfer, and if you need to transfer you need to call the Apple Customer support and then we will do it.

**6. Can I use the same App name after the account to which it belongs expires?

Ans:** You can use the same name only if you transfer that App from the old developer account to new developer account. As every App name is unique in AppStore. And there is also app data maintained for each single App, even if you delete an App from the App Store, Apple will store and maintain the app data, So you can’t create a App with the same name even if you delete the App as Apple will maintain the app data related to that particular App. But you really want to upload a different App with the same name, you after deleting you App need to call Apple Customer support and request them to delete the "app data” which was maintained by them for the App which you just deleted. And after Apple deletes that “app data” you can create a new app with the same name.

**7. In an enterprise account can I create developer account and publish App to the App Store ?

Ans:** No

**8. Can I use the same id to create both Developer and Enterprise account ?

Ans:** No

**9. In my old account I have some member added in people section with different roles, will that also gets transferred?

Ans:** No, You need to add them again to the new developer account.

**10. When I transfer will all the TestFlight data also gets transferred ?

Ans:** No

**11. After App transfer, will the already installed Application will work correctly ?

Ans:** Yes

**12. And if I push update for the App, from the new developer account will the already installed App get the update?

Ans:** Yes, they will get the new update, for them there will be no difference.

**13. App ratings and user reviews will also get transfer to the new developer account ?

Ans:** Yes

**14. App id for the App will also remain same after transferred to new account right ?

Ans:** yes

**15. What if the App has some payment related to it and the previous account had some bank details added for that?

Ans:** If this is the case then we need to first add the bank details, and then initiate the transfer.

**Have a nice day :)**

Answer (score 0):

Your App status says **"Prepare for submission"** and there is no published version so you have to get your app published first and as mentioned in the Apple's documentation "*The app should have at least one published version for transfer*".

[image]

Comment: Then what I require to do? if I want to use same application name at other account. This app already no published in market and I want to change app account.

Comment: This isn't 100% accurate. The app does have to have at least one published version, but it can be in one of several states, as listed in the documentation.

Comment: @Moshe I have added your remarks in the answer. My answer was accroding to the image in the question.